# Add enum property to existing dropdown menu

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

Under the render settings in the bake panel there is a 'bake type' dropdown menu.
Each of the options within this is enumerated, however I want to be able to add my own option to this drop-down box.

using:

```
bpy.types.CyclesRenderSettings.bake_type.__add__(my_tuple_item)
```

doesn't actually add anything to the menu, and the structure remains the same.
Is adding to this property group allowed?

Would there be a better way of going about it (apart from editing the source code)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scene.cycles.bake_type`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.CyclesRenderSettings.html#bpy.types.CyclesRenderSettings.bake_type) is already registered as a property of the [`CyclesRenderSettings`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_4/bpy.types.CyclesRenderSettings.html#module-bpy.types) class.  We can get the details of the enum from the class itself, or in the example below from  the instance; `scene.cycles.rna_type.properties("bake_type")`

Add a new item to the enum property list and redefine the property with our appended list.

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import EnumProperty

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
prop = scene.cycles.rna_type.properties["bake_type"]
items = [(i.identifier, i.name, i.description, i.icon, i.value) 
              for i in prop.enum_items.values()]

# add one
if 'FOO' not in [i[0] for i in items]:
    items.append(('FOO', "Foo", "New Foo Item", 'NONE', 11))

    bpy.types.CyclesRenderSettings.bake_type = EnumProperty(
                                             name=prop.name,
                                             description=prop.description,
                                             default=prop.default,
                                             items=items)
```

Would need to append a draw method to the panel that recognises the new enum prop 'FOO'.

Note: could get some hassles if cycles code doesn't know what to do with your new bake_type.